# Providing an OAuth Javascript API

Tags: javascript, api, oauth, oauth-2.0, oauth-provider

I'm setting up a website to be an OAuth 2.0 provider, much like Facebook and Twitter. Both these sites enable you to "Login with Facebook/Twitter" via a button, which opens an auth dialog. Once the user signs in, the box is closed and the requesting page now has the access token. **How are they doing this in a way that doesn't violate cross-domain policies?**

It seems to be that the Facebook JS SDK is loaded from their server, is this intentional to get around x-domain restrictions?

Also, at what point is the access token received by the parent window? Is it sent by the child or fetched by the parent?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by passing value from child widow to parent window. Every child window which is opened by parent window has reference to his parent which is can be access by:

```
var parent = window.opener.document.document; // by this you have reference to parent DOM
var someParentElement = parent.getElementById("idOfParentDomElement"); // ex: accessing particular element on parent
```

So by this you can pass value to parent by accessing it parent:

```
var childDiv = document.getElemntById("SomeChildDiv").innerHTML;
someParentElement.innerHTML = childDiv // passing html text to parent div
```

Read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.opener)

Receiving access token is part of [OAuth flow](http://oauth.net/) . Through oauth token is received and passes to parent window by `window.opener` and then `window.close` called by parent window to close window. After this parent work with Access Token.

**Edit: After comments:**

Facebook use a postMessage, iframe or flash functionality to handle cross-domain messaging which depend on browser. It includes `all.js` which is a key file to handle messages between. You can read more about its mechanism [here](http://hustoknow.blogspot.in/2012/06/facebooks-cross-domain-handler-upgrades.html)

Comment: I'll give this a try, thanks. Will accept as answer if I'm successful. ;)

Comment: This will work. I usually do this. If you face some problem then post in comment.

Comment: This would generally work if the domain of the auth dialog was the same as the window opener, but it isn't. So window.opener has no properties because they're on different domains.

Comment: First try to understan how auth flow work? And window.opener works as in the flow end both domains are same. Try to implement it when you have undestood auth process.

Comment: Take a look at Facebook's OAuth implementation. In their case, after authorization the dialog box never directs back to the requesting domain. The window is redirected to xd_arbiter.php on one of Facebook's domains - and then it is closed. Looking at xd_arbiter.php reveals a lot of different shims for what appears to be XDC - so I guess my question is more about how all that works.

Comment: whats the full url for xd_arbiter.php?

Comment: Here's the full URL from the auth dialog (using ESPN as an example): https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?app_id=116656161708917&client_id=116656161708917&display=popup&domain=r.espn.go.com&e2e=%7B%7D&locale=en_US&origin=1&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D27%23cb%3Df2fc8069b8%26domain%3Dr.espn.go.com%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fr.espn.go.com%252Ff202a028%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df1926afad8&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&scope=email%2Cuser_birthday%2Cuser_likes&sdk=joey

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/read thats the final url i got. Can you paste exact url of xd_arbiter.php only

Comment: `https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=27#cb=f2fc8069b8&domain=r.espn.go.com&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fr.espn.go.com%2Ff202a028&relation=opener&frame=f1926afad8` is the value of OAuth's `redirect_uri`

Comment: Thanks for your detective work. What a pain in the arse hahah